# Laravel & LEMP: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx

Running php artisan migrate results in error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations 
and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Server is running Ubuntu 18.04. PHP7.3, nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu), mysql 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1.

I`ve tried connecting to the DB with the given user and password, it works.

```
# Database
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

MySQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE homestead;

GRANT ALL ON homestead.* to 'homestead'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: have you created `homestead` database .? fix that add correct database and user and password

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes, I`ve added the commands I did to my post.

Comment: and mysql password `secret` is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix your `host`

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

to

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```